# Android SDK installation failed (Jenkins' Android Emulator plugin) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to donwload SDK archive

Tags: android, jenkins, sdk

I've been trying to integrate Android Emulator in my Jenkins workflow on my Windows PC using [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-emulator/). I've been facing this error.

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Users\user\.jenkins\workspace\Testing if android emulator works
[android] Outdated SDK Tools found. Upgrading from '26.1.1' to 'build 6609375'
[android] Android SDK installation failed
[android] hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstallationException: Failed to download Android SDK
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.doInstall(SdkInstaller.java:91)
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.install(SdkInstaller.java:72)
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.AndroidEmulator.setUp(AndroidEmulator.java:278)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:157)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to donwload SDK archive
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.installBasicSdk(SdkInstaller.java:189)
    at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.doInstall(SdkInstaller.java:89)
    ... 8 more

Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

I have taken the following steps after seeing people's discussions on SO and other websites (but haven't been able to resolve the issue):

- Updated to latest android skd, and sdk command line tools. Also, updated possibly everything else that I could from Android Studio.
- Added windows/system32 in path in env variables
- Ran cmd as admin to run jenkins (realised later that it's a bad idea as scripts can do anything)
- Went to http://localhost:8080/configure > set Android SDK root variable.
- Went to http://localhost:8080/configure > tick Environment variables > set ANDROID_HOME & JAVA_HOME variables.
- Went to http://localhost:8080/configureTools/ > set jdk installation.

Note: I've verified that all environment variables are correct.

Here's some of my thought process:

- The error message says that it's trying to update tools from v 26.1.1 to a newer version. But I don't even have sdk tools of this version in my Android SDK!
- This may hint to a dual installation of Android sdk but there only one. And after that, I don't know what's wrong...

I'm stuck on this for several days now & any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you ever solved the problem ?

Comment: @DkP nope. I actually got a new PC, reinstalled everying, it then ran file. Still gives the same issue on the older one.

Answer (score 0):

In the ENV, you specified paths to internal Android SDK tools? For example, you add to PATH `/emulator` and `/platform-tools` folders? This folders contains in the Android SDK root.

Comment: I have the following in path: Sdk\platform-tools, \Sdk\emulator, \Sdk\tools\emulator, \Sdk\cmdline-tools. Still gives the same error.

Comment: This variables defined on the Windows machine locally or in the Jenkins settings (for concrete machine)?

Comment: The variables have been defined locally on my windows machine. However, as per my understanding they do get recognized by Jenkins for 2 reasons: 1) emulator -list-avds command works in Jenkins 2) All path variables of my local machine are reflected in Dashboard> My project > Environment variables (image for reference: https://ibb.co/pRPYcXJ

Comment: Try add Android SDK paths to Jenkins ENV. Just now I am deleted ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and some paths from PATH in Jenkins settings for server and facing with same issue.

Comment: Appreciate the response. But as reflected in my question, I've already added Android SDK root, JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME in Jenkins.

Comment: Try to use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT instead of ANDROID_HOME (because it's [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables)). Also you can try update tools manually by [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line#tools-sdk) link (on this site you can find instructions to setup tools).

Comment: I added ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable both in Jenkins and my Windows PC. And I have verified that my command line tools are up to date. Still, the exact same error pops up.